# Subscript out of range (small comparation and return to other array)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have create the following code. I want verify if my arry1 is equal to "Gi0". If is correct then copy to a new arry2, but then appear the following error:

> Subscript out of range

Can someone explain me what is wrong?
with :

```
arry2(k, 1) = arry1(i, 1)



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim arry1() As Variant
ReDim arry2(1 To 20, 1 To 1)

arry1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B65").Value

k = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(ar1)
If Left(arry1(i, 1), 3) = "Gi0" Then
arry2(k, 1) = arry1(i, 1)
k = k + 1
Else
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you define `ar1`?  And you probably get your subscript out of range error when `k` (somehow, I don't know how) gets to more than 20 - i.e. if your loop ran, you found more than 20 matches.

Comment: @YowE3K is right. It looks like you did not define `ar1`. Maybe you should try with `For i=1 To Ubound(arry1) Step 1`

Comment: Sorry ar1 is array1. My mistake. But still give the same error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Ubound(ar1) and your array is called arry1.

Also, you don't need an ELSE statement in your IF.

And is that a good way to dim or redim an array? I don't think so.

If I want arry2 to be a 21 by 2 array then I say

```
dim arry2(20,1) as double.
```

If you want to dim in terms of variables I say:

```
dim arry2() as double
redim arry2(x,y)
```

Comment: Also, remember arrays start with 0 as first index.

Comment: `arry2` will have 0 as the first index (unless `Option Base 1` is used, or 1 is specified as the explicit base as the OP did), but the OP's `arry1` will have 1 as the first index because it was created by `arry1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B65").Value` - it will be a `1 To 64, 1 To 1` array.

Comment: @YowE3K Ah yes you are right, sorry OP - 8:30PM here and I'm answering Stack questions at a bar! woe is me

Comment: Alcohol and tiredness - definitely a dangerous combination!!  :D